# PHP send mail HELP

Tags: php, email

I am using this function to send an email, but this does nto work..

What's wrong?? =(

```
<?php

$SMTP = "mailer2.mondoweb.it";
$TO = "test@yobilab.com";


function InviaMail($subject, $body, $hdrs) {
    global $SMTP, $TO;
    ini_set("SMTP", $SMTP);
    mail($TO, $subject, $body, $hdrs);
}



$subject =  "Clevery. Richiesta informazioni su: ". $_POST['offerta'] .".";

    $body = "Clevery. Richiesta informazioni su: ". $_POST['offerta'] ."<br><br>" .
            "Nome cliente: " . $_POST['nome'] . "<br>" .
                        "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>" .
            "Referente: " . $_POST['referente'] . "<br>" .
            "Città: " . $_POST['citta'] . "<br>" .
            "Provincia: " . $_POST['provincia'] . "<br>" .
            "Telefono: " . $_POST['telefono'] . "<br>" .
            "Note: " . $_POST['commento'] . "<br>";

    $hdrs = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n" . "From: " .
            "\"clevery.it\" <info@clevery.it>";
InviaMail($subject, $body, $hdrs);
?>
```

Comment: your server have sendmail or something equivalent to send email ? :)

Comment: What are the error messages or at least the symptoms!

Comment: Absolutely nothing. No errors, nothing. The email is not sent out. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: What does your `mail()` call return: true or false?

Comment: The mail function does not know if the mail made it off your server, only that PHP handed the mail to the local mail server to send. If `mail()` returns true, you should check your mail log to find out what happened after that.

Comment: How do I check if it returns true or false?

Comment: @DiegoP Eep, scary question, how did you write this code without knowing how functions work? `$returnvalue = mail($TO, $subject, $body, $hdrs; echo "Return value was: $returnvalue";`

Comment: It just returns empty. I do not see any true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php 
    function InviaMail($subject, $body, $hdrs) {
        global $SMTP, $TO;
        ini_set("SMTP", $SMTP);
        if(mail($TO, $subject, $body, $hdrs)===true){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

   echo (InviaMail($subject, $body, $hdrs)===true)?'Mail was sent.':'Error Sending mail.'
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SMTP used Port 25 to send mails which is blocked by most of the ISP's to check if it is the problem with your code or your ISP try doing this.

```
echo mail($to, $subject, $body, $hdrs) ? 'Mail Sent Successfully' : 'There was an error sending mail';
```

Try the above code.